# Entity Framework code first: one-to-one-or-zero association to derived object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, code-first

I want to accomplish this model:
[image]
[image]

I've been trying many ways, but nothing works. Thats, for example, the code what I think it should be:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cage> Cages { get; set; }
}

public class Cage
{
    public int CageID { get; set; }
    public Bird Bird { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public int AnimalID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    [ForeignKey("Cage")]
    public int CageID { get; set; }
    public Cage Cage { get; set; }
}

public class Shark : Animal
{
    public int AquariumID { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is called Table Per Type.

You can do this 2 ways, first way is by using Data annotation `[Table("Bird")]` likewise for your `Shark`

Or if you prefer doing fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bird>().ToTable("Bird");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Shark>().ToTable("Shark");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the key value from animal to bird and shark.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CageID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CageID")]
    public virtual Cage Cage { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool CanFly { get; set; }
}

public class Shark : Animal
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public bool CanSwim { get; set; }
}
```

then you can see the result in database like below.

[image]

Hope it help to you.

Comment: Then I get the error `EntityType 'Animal' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.` Are you changed something else in my code snippet?

Comment: @Feofilakt I added Animal abstract class now. can you try please again.

Comment: No, the idea is that not any Animal has Cage property. For example, the Shark is not in Cage, but in Aquarium

Comment: I see now. As I undestand before aquarium also is a cage type. So you can move to cage properties to bird.

Comment: @Feofilakt did you try again ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but have you tried the "virtual" statement?

```
public class Bird : Animal
{
    public virtual Cage cage{ get; set; }
}
```

This enables lazy loading which causes EntityFramework to do all the work for you:

```
Bird Polly = new Bird{cage = new Cage()};
```

Not sure about your way of generating IDs, might have to add  `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the "Id" Field.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Cage can't refer to a single Bird since Bird.CageId is not the key of Bird.  So you can declare it as a 1-many relationship, but put a unique constraint on Bird.CageId so no two birds can actually be in the same cage.  Like this:

```
   public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cage> Cages { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cage
    {
        public int CageID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Bird> Birds { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public int AnimalID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bird : Animal
    {
        [ForeignKey("Cage"),Index(IsUnique =true)]
        public int CageID { get; set; }
        public Cage Cage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shark : Animal
    {
        public int AquariumID { get; set; }
    }
```

Another option is to put the Foreign Key on Cage:

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cage> Cages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Bird>().HasOptional(b => b.Cage).WithRequired(c => c.Bird);
        }
    }

    public class Cage
    {
        [Key]
        public int CageId { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CageId")]
        public virtual Bird Bird { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public int AnimalID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bird : Animal
    {
        public Cage Cage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shark : Animal
    {
        public int AquariumID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Then I will have to write `cage.Birds.First()` every time and to keep in mind that it is only one item in collection. It does not look good.

Comment: Added another option.

Comment: In this case I get association `Cage: 0..1 - Bird: 1`, but I need `Cage: 1 - Bird: 0..1`